# How to change to avoid copying the contents of the pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

**EDIT 3**

I have the following code

```
std::shared_ptr<int> original = std::make_shared<int>(5);
std::shared_ptr<int> other = std::make_shared<int>(6);
std::stack<std::shared_ptr<int>> todo;
todo.push(original);
std::shared_ptr<int> temp = todo.top();
*temp = *other;

std::cout << original << other << temp << std::endl;
```

`original` now points to the resource `6` and the output in the console is then `666`.
I like to avoid the copy `*temp = *other` as the real value I use in the pointers and stack are expensive to copy.

Comment: Do you prefer to carry forward old value of p1 with P2s value?  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Maybe I don't get it... [But what is wrong with `p1 = p2;`?](https://ideone.com/ArVAhm)

Comment: Would `p2.swap(p1);` not do the trick?

Comment: @satanik Everyone's having trouble understanding what you're asking. Say you have two `shared_ptr`s, both owning the same resource - `auto p1 = std::make_shared<int>(10); auto p2 = p1;` Now what do you want to have happen? Do you want to replace the `10` with another value, so that both `*p1` and `*p2` will yield the new value? Or are you asking something else? I'd suggest getting rid of the `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<int>>` example unless it's necessary, and explaining your problem in a simple manner.

Comment: @Praetorian I tried to add a more understandable example

Comment: Your more understandable example *isn't*.

Comment: @MarkRansom sorry. This is exactly the example I have in my code. At least it is the relevant code. I do not know how to make it more understandable. But maybe you can tell me which part you do not understand.

Comment: `other` is also a `std::shared_ptr<ExpensiveToCopy>`, and you don't want to do `*current = *other;` because you want to avoid the copy, is that correct? If so, your `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<ExpensiveToCopy>>` idea should work, all you have to do is `*current = *other;`

Comment: @satanik: I think you'll get the best help if you first post completely unoptimized code that does what you're doing in the simplest and most straightforward way. e.g. imagine `ExpensiveToCopy` was just `int`. In particular, copies are fine, and maybe you wouldn't have even bothered with pointers and dynamic allocations. *Then*, you can ask the question "What needs to change to eliminate the cost of making expensive copies?"

Comment: @Praetorian this is exactly what I want to do. But wouldn't `*current = *other;` result in an invalid call? Because `current` is a pointer to a pointer and `other` is just a pointer, so I thought about `*current = other`. But as I pointed out in the previous example most people had problems with understanding, this does not work as I guess `*current` is also a copy of `original`. Sorry for the entanglements.

Comment: @Hurkyl this sounds like a good plan. Is it ok if I do this in this post, or do I have to delete this one and ask a new question therefore?

Comment: Here is probably good; I think the answer is still a bit speculative about your needs, so nothing is harmed by drastically changing the content of the original post.

Comment: @satanik  I think you are dealing with cyclic reference,  I corrected my answer using weak_ptr, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to keep going with using pointer to pointer.

```
//we need to make shared pointer to shared pointer
const std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<int>> orginal = 
        std::make_shared<std::shared_ptr<int>>(std::make_shared<int>(5));
// const pp1 must be declarated before p1 to make sure p1 is valid 
std::shared_ptr<int> &p1 = *orginal;
std::shared_ptr<int> p2 = std::make_shared<int>(6);
cout << *p1 << *p2 << endl;
std::stack<std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<int>>> todo;
//we cannot add p1, instead we need to add orginal
todo.push(orginal); 
std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<int>> temp = todo.top();
//this does change the orginal
*temp = p2;
cout << *p1 << *p2 << endl;
```

No, you cannot change in that way `p2`, it is alocated on stack, and keeping pointer to stack inside shared_ptr would be very incomprehensible.

Anyway, I think that you might looking for flyweight pattern, [see this](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.flyweight).

Comment: Is there a way to do it without making `original` a pointer to pointer? because in my case it is only a pointer and is often used. So if I change it that way I have to change all of the other code as well.

Comment: @satanik No you cannot do that saftly. As I said p2 cannot be in my example. But you can use a reference p1 as long as you keep one copyright of orginal pointer to pointer alive. If you declared p2 inside a structure that also is managed by stared_ptr, you can covert that stared_ptr to our pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use `weak_ptr` as template argument of stack you can achieve what you are looking for:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> original = std::make_shared<int>(5);
std::shared_ptr<int> other = std::make_shared<int>(6);
std::stack<std::weak_ptr<int>> todo;
todo.push(original);
std::weak_ptr<int> temp = todo.top();
temp=other;

std::cout << *original.get() << *other.get() << *temp.lock().get() << std::endl;
std::cout<<"use_count: original:"<< original.use_count()<<"\n";
std::cout<<"use_count: other:"<< other.use_count()<<"\n";
```

output: 
566

use_count: original:1

use_count: other:1

**EDIT:**

```
std::shared_ptr<int> original = std::make_shared<int>(5);
std::shared_ptr<int> other = std::make_shared<int>(6);
std::stack<std::weak_ptr<int>> todo;
todo.push(original);
std::weak_ptr<int> temp = todo.top();
temp=other;
original= other;

std::cout << *original.get() << *other.get() << *temp.lock().get() << std::endl;
std::cout<<"use_count: original:"<< original.use_count()<<"\n";
std::cout<<"use_count: other:"<< other.use_count()<<"\n";
std::cout<<"use_count: temp:"<< temp.use_count()<<"\n";
```

output:
666

use_count: original:2

use_count: other:2

use_count: temp:2

Comment: But this is exactly what I cannot use, as the actual `p1` I use later on is a copy of `p1`. I wrote it in the description before AND in the comment directly above the assignment. I will pass the pointer to e.g. a stack and then retrieve it again, the stack makes a copy of it and then it is another pointer, if I then assign `stack.top() = p2` - `p1` will still hold the original value

Comment: You should have said, further changes in `*p2` will reflect in `*p1`.  Because your actual claim that "any further changes in p2 will reflect in p1 too" is incorrect.

Comment: I wanted the output `666` so `*origianl` should be `6`.

Comment: @Steephen: I see that this works, but I need to make `*original == 6` when assigning `temp = other` because at that point of the program `original` is not available (e.g. inside a loop where temp is the current value of stack but not necessarily the `original` pointer)